# Trying to get Perl script to count properly the number of results from grep of process

Tags: perl, grep

All,

I am trying to grep for a particular process that contains the listed paths(shown in my @t_processes array)in its output.  The count will always be one as the command you use to grep will also show in the output by default.  So I am using if the count is greater than 1, that it is indeed running. All of these processes are up when I grep them, and there are at least two results that come back on the command line.  But when I run the script I only get back the print statement of:  "Process $t_process is matched! Is it running?....".  Can anyone offer some guidance?

```
use strict;
use warnings;


sub main
{

my @t_processes = (
'/hosting/configs/tomcat7/prod-06_fc' ,
'/hosting/configs/tomcat7/prod-07_fc',
'/hosting/configs/tomcat7/prod-07',
'/hosting/configs/apache22/prod-06_fc/',
'/hosting/configs/jboss6/jb-prod-06'
);

foreach
    my $t_process(@t_processes)
{
    my $match_count = 0;
    if(`ps -aef | grep -i $t_process`) 
    {

        print "Process $t_process is matched! Is it running?....";
        if($match_count > 1)
            {
                print "The process is running\n ";
            }   
        else
            {
                $match_count++
            }                           

    }
    else 
    {
        print "The process $t_process is not running, please start it!\n" ;
    }


}

}


main();
```

Comment: your logic is fatally flawed. `$match_count` will never be more than zero, as you reset it at the onset of each `for()` loop. Not only that, it's zero when you check if it is greater than 1 which it can't be, then fall through to the `else()` and `++` it, but nothing will ever see the increased value because you just start the next loop after that else.

Answer (score 1):

Your grep if condition is always succeeding because grep itself produces one result, therefore the if condition is always satisfied.

Try running

```
if(`ps -aef | grep -i $t_process | grep -v grep`)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment on your OP, your `$match_count` logic is fatally flawed. First, you declare it inside of the `for()` loop, which will reset it to zero on every process. Second, you never assign to it, except later in the `else()` statement; by then, you're about to fall out of the loop.

Here's a much simpler approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @t_processes = qw(nginx blah);

for my $t_process(@t_processes){
    if(`ps -aef | grep -i $t_process | grep -v grep`){
        print "$t_process is running\n";
        next;
    }
    print "$t_process is not running, please start it!\n" ;
}
```

Output:

```
nginx is running
blah is not running, please start it!
```